# How to open files using theirs default application in SilverLight Webapplication?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Can anyone please suggest a method to open the the files using their
default application in Silverlight application. I am able to get the
full path of the files that I am selecting.

That is for verifying the files before uploading. While using this:

`AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(FileList[_index].filepath);‌`​

I get

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Its not working if the filename contains **whitespaces** in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open filepaths with spaces you need to add quotes arround your path. Try to use:

`"\"" + FILE_PATH + "\""`

In your code:

```
AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("\"" + FileList[_index].filepath + "\"");‌
```

Comment: No,I am able to open files in certain directories,but not from all directories.I think its kind of security issue.

Comment: You are able to read the content of the files (for example with an upload dialog) but you are not able to "start" client applications and this is what I mean with client resources. What kind of files do you want to open? What kind of files are you able to open?

Comment: I have an application,in which i need to upload(attach) files.While i'm trying to view these files using system applications ,iam getting exceptions.

Comment: I have some questions: If you want to upload the files, why you want to open them on the client (Or do you mean reading the uploaded files)? What exceptions do you get?

Comment: That is for verifying the files before uploading.I am able to upload those files which having problems in viewing.Obviously,after uploading i am able to view the files.
While using this `AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(FileList[_index].filepath);`

i am getting `System.Io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Its not working if the filename contains whitespaces in it.

Comment: Try `AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""" & FileList[_index].filepath & """");‌`. You should update your question with the given informations in the comments.

Comment: @NithinVvn I updated my question. I hope this helps you.